# Problem with refreshing ListView

Tags: android, listview, refresh

The problem is: I have problem with refreshing listView. I set ListView adapter (BaseAdapter) after changing data object I call notifyDataSetChanged but it make no effect to my list - its stay empty. None of Adapter function is called!

What i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling requery() on your cursor?